# JavaFX Cant apply any animation class to "stage"

Tags: java, javafx

I wanna apply any transition class but their `.setNode()` method only accepts `Node` which does not accept `scene` or `stage`. How can i do animations on directly stage? Below code gives error;

```
  TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition();
    transition.setFromX(1000);
    transition.setFromY(1000);
    transition.setToX(500);
    transition.setToY(500);

    transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(5));
    transition.setNode(stage);
    transition.play();
```

Comment: You can use the low level `Timeline` class and interpolate on stage's x/y properties.

Comment: any example on translation property? stage.xProperty is readonly

Comment: Right but you can still call `setX(double)`. You'll have to listen for changes on an arbitrary `DoubleProperty` caused by the timeline and set the stage properties with its value.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `Transition` and override the `interpolate` method to call `setX()` and `setY()`:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.Transition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AnimatedWindow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(), 400, 400));
        Animation transition = new Transition() {

            private final double startX = 1000 ;
            private final double endX = 500 ;

            private final double startY = 1000 ;
            private final double endY = 500 ;

            {
                setCycleDuration(Duration.seconds(5));
            }

            @Override
            protected void interpolate(double frac) {
                double x = frac * endX + (1 - frac) * startX ;
                double y = frac * endY + (1 - frac) * startY ;
                primaryStage.setX(x);
                primaryStage.setY(y);
            }

        };

        primaryStage.show();

        transition.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```